# percentile_cont signature error when calculating median

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

Hi I have a table "masterdata" with the following structure:

user_eng_time, day, user_pseudo_id

I am running the following code:

```
select percentile_cont(x,0.5) over () as median_time_in_seconds
from( 
select round(user_eng_time/1000) from masterdata 
) as x
```

I am getting the following error:

```
No matching signature for aggregate function PERCENTILE_CONT for argument types: STRUCT<FLOAT64>, FLOAT64. Supported signatures: PERCENTILE_CONT(FLOAT64, FLOAT64); PERCENTILE_CONT(NUMERIC, NUMERIC); PERCENTILE_CONT(BIGNUMERIC, BIGNUMERIC) at [55:8]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`percentile_cont` expects as first entry a float value and not a table. In your case, you can use `x.col` to reference on table `x` and the column `col`.

```sql
With masterdata as (
  Select 10000*rand() as user_eng_time 
  from unnest(generate_array(1,100))
  )

select *,percentile_cont(x.col,0.5) over () as median_time_in_seconds
from( 
select round(user_eng_time/1000) as col from masterdata 
) as x
```